# Merge 2 columns with numbers and NULL cells (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, merge

I have an attribut table with 2 columns like this :
Column A     Column B
22            NULL
23            NULL
24            NULL
25            NULL
26            NULL
NULL          52
NULL          53
NULL          54
NULL          55

I want to take the numbers of B (52 to 55) and replace the NULLs of the column A with these numbers like this :
COLUMN A
22
23
24
25
26
52
53
54

Aggregate or concatenate or & or + doesn't work in the field calculator because there are NULL in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new field with an expression:

```
coalesce( "Column A" , "Column B" )
```

Then rename the field to `COLUMN A`.

Comment: i just did that but the result is a copy of column B

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression to update COLUMN A for all features:

> IF( "COLUMN A" IS NOT NULL,  "COLUMN A" ,  "COLUMN B" )

[image]

Result: 
[image]